# Access UI from OnClick in GetView

Tags: android

I have a custom adapter for gridview.

```
    public class PDFAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ...

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater
                    .inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);

        }

        Button1 = (Button) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button2 = (Button) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.button2);

        Button1 .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Button2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

        });
        Button2 .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Button1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

        });

        return convertView;
    }
...

}
```

My problem is here, I cannot access the UI from onClick method for View.INVISIBLE. There is nothing change after I clicked both the button. What am I missing?

Comment: The views are reused, so this won't work as you expect. You will have to create an List to keep track of which row should hide its buttons or not.

Comment: In another word, you must change to state of the data and call notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: is it after setting the setvisibility, call notifyDataSetChanged()?